# Apache mod_rewrite - forward domain root to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have what I originally assumed to be a simple problem. I am using shared hosting for my website (so I don't have access to the Apache configuration) and have only been given a single folder to store all my content in. This is all well and good but it means that all my subdomains must have their virtual document root's inside `public_html`, meaning they effectively become a folder on my main domain.

What I'd like to do is organise my `public_html` something like this:

```
public_html/
    www/
        index.php
        ...
    sub1/
        index.php
        ...
    some_library/
        ...
```

This way, all my web content is still in `public_html` but only a small fraction of it will be served to the client. I can easily achieve this for all the subdomains, but it's the primary domain that I'm having issues with.

I created a `.htaccess` file in `public_html` with the following:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch # I'm not allowed to use FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

This works fairly well, but for some strange reason `www.example.com/stuff` is translated into a *request* for `www.example.com/www/stuff` and hence a 404 error is given. It was my understanding that unless an 'R' flag was specified, mod_rewrite was purely internal so I can't understand why the request is generated as that implies (to me at least) redirection.

I assumed this would be a trivial problem to solve as all I actually want to do is forward all requests for the root of `www.example.com` to a subdirectory, but I've spent hours searching for answers and none are quite correct. I find it difficult to believe I'm the only person to have this issue.

I apologise if this question has been answered on here before, I did search and trawl but couldn't find an appropriate answer. Please could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix this myself. It turns out that Apache remembers folder settings even after the `.htaccess` file has been removed. So as I'd been playing with this for so long, some of my earlier attempts had completely polluted the config.

I solved it by first commenting all of the `.htaccess` file out apart from `RewriteEngine off` which put everything (almost) back to normal. Then I managed to get the desired effect by writing the following config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$   www/   [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) www/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Finally, I created another `.htaccess` file in the `www` directory containing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
```

Now everything seems to work as I originally wanted. Shame it took so long to work all this out though!